# Editing properties of a Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have an byte array of an doc file loaded in memory.

I would like to set custom meta data properties of my Word document then save it back to disk. This will be done on a server so I can’t use VTSO to write an add in.

I need to do this in a 2003 word document. so I can't use open xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx)? Or you can use [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) API directly.

Comment: +1. Been there, done that. The Packaging API that Mike suggests will crack open the files for you.  The SDK will give you access to the internal files in a strongly-typed way, so adding custom meta-data will be easier wity the SDK.

Comment: Open XML is a great solusion but I need to do this to word 2003 documents.

Comment: It is prabably better to start new qestion and rollback original question. As someone could have the same question.